# edittext size is different for username and password

Tags: android, android-edittext

i have edittext for user name, password, server name with hint as "required", but i have a issue, the text size is different whereas in coding it is same only.

[image]

how to over come that,

my xml code for textview alone is,

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sapuser"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:hint="Required"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:width="150dip" />  

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:hint="Required"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:password="true"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/host"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:hint="Required"
                android:paddingLeft="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text=""
                android:width="150dip" />
```

Comment: look closer, you'll find the font family is different as well.

Comment: use like this  android:textSize="10pt"

Comment: You can give textsize="15dp" of edit text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because of height, you have not set it...this will work

```
<EditText
 android:id="@+id/sapuser"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_column="2"
 android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
 android:hint="Required"
 android:paddingLeft="5dip"
 android:singleLine="true"
 android:text=""
 android:textSize="20dp"

 android:width="150dip" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:hint="Required"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:password="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/host"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:hint="Required"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:width="150dip"
            android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Comment: it is not working. . .

Comment: use linear layout and give width 0px for each editbox and also check this link would be helpful to resolve your problem http://tekeye.biz/2012/android-textview-edittext-font

Comment: if it is solved mark your question done..

Comment: The URL given in the comment above has changed, it is now https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/android-textview-edittext-font